# Order of records in subform reverting to default when selecting different parent record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I feel like this should be simple, but I've been trying/failing to fix and searching for an answer for hours... I am building a database to keep track of animal "inventory". I have a parent form which tracks the animals themselves (what kind, breed, color, where it came from, etc). Linked to each parent record is a subset of records on a subform which tracks what/how much they eat, size, weight, and some health concerns, all unique to each individual animal and ordered by date. This subform gets quite hefty, and I don't want to have to scroll down to the bottom of it each time I need to add a new one. I've tried several different methods of getting around the issue, including jumping to the last record (on Load, Entry, and all kinds of other form controls). The best result I've gotten so far is On Load: this works when I first open the parent form; however, as soon as I change the parent record to another animal, the subform view reverts to default, displaying the first record instead of the last. I tried adding a second subform strictly for data entry, but a similar thing happens. Upon opening the parent form to the default record, this data entry form is blank; but as soon as I change to a new animal on the parent form, instead the data entry form shows the earliest record. What would be the best way to make a subform jump to the last record when selecting a new record on the parent form? Another acceptable workaround would be to display only a limited number of the most recent details from the subform (e.g. 3 or 4). Using Access 2010. I appreciate any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

In using a second subform as a data-entry form, I discovered that all I needed to do was change the form type from Continuous to Single. After doing so, it always displays only blank fields to enter new data into. This being the case, it doesn't matter how the original subform is ordered in this particular situation.

However, if someone else would still like to pose a response to the issue of the subform's order reverting to default (ascending) when I change the record I'm viewing on the parent form, that would still be helpful for me in other situations!